# Unsolved murder GIS datasets

Tags: crime

does anyone know if there are any datasets published regarding unsolved serial murders within the United States?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% what you seek, but the [Murder Accountability Project](http://www.murderdata.org/) is an open database of unsolved murders in America, and provides an algorithm for specifically seeking out serial homicides. You can read [more about it here](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2017/11/27/the-serial-killer-detector).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download crime datasets on google. Here is an example :

https://www.bjs.gov/rawdata.cfm

https://www.justice.gov/open/open-data

https://www.lib.umn.edu/libdata/page_print.phtml?page_id=2258